# autotest shows blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest, zentest

I installed the autotest gem and intend to use it with rspec. The problem is, when I run autotest under my rails app, all I see is :

> railsapp$ **autospec**
>
> loading autotest/rails_rspec
>
> ---

And its stuck there until I Ctrl-C out of it. Nothing changes even if I change a rspec test or code.

Here's my ~/.autotest

> require "autotest/restart"
>
> require 'redgreen/autotest'
>
> require 'autotest/fsevent'
>
> require "autotest/growl"

Comment: Does running it with `-v` say the spec equivalent of `No tests matched test\tc_foo.rb`?

Comment: Yes, it does say that.Any ideas ?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Verbose mode tells me "No tests matched".

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.  I was eventually able to get everything working by making sure I was on the latest (beta, if necessary) versions of rspec, rspec-rails, autotest, and autotest-rails, and putting the following in autotest/discovery.rb:

```
Autotest.add_discovery { "rails" }
Autotest.add_discovery { "rspec2" }
```

Here's [the blog post](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2010/03/15/rspec-2-and-autotest/) that got me started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and this fixed it:

"Make sure you have a .rspec file in the project root. That tells RSpec to tell Autotest to load RSpec’s autotest extension."

ref: https://github.com/rspec/rspec/wiki/autotest

It seems as if my .rspec file had gotten deleted when messing around with git.

Answer (score 0):

Cd into app directory and run the command: AUTOFEATURE=true autospec

To stop this process ^C twice

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Rails 2.3.2 except that I'm not using RSpec.  In my case, installing the `autotest-rails-pure` gem got it working for me.  Maybe autotest requires the correct plugin in order to detect a test within a file.